# Ui Bootstrap (angularjs) sidenav doesn't work as intended

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, css, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a problem with a sidenav which I'm trying to create for one of my projects. My intention is to create a side menu which pushes the content to the right when is opened and when closed the content should move back to the left, sort of a toggle function. For some reason my ternary operator doesn't work as intended.

Here is my snippet:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<html ng-app="uiBootstrapBlog">
  <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
    <script src="https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.5.0.js"></script>
    <link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
<body>
<div ng-controller="navbarCtrl">
 <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
   <div class="container-fluid">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
   <li style="font-size:30px; cursor:pointer;color:white" ng-click="isCollapsedHorizontal = !isCollapsedHorizontal" ng-model="singleModel" uib-btn-checkbox>&#9776;</li>
  </ul>
  
   </div>
 </nav>
 <div style="position: fixed; width: 230px">
  <div class="horizontal-collapse" uib-collapse="isCollapsedHorizontal" horizontal style="  margin-top: 50px !important; min-height: 150px; max-height: 80vh; background: gray; color: black; padding-top: 25px;" >    
  </div>
 </div>
 <div style="position: absolute; top: 60px; transition: left .5s;" id="main">grhgerhrehrehre<br>grhgerhrehrehre<br>grhgerhrehrehre<br>grhgerhrehrehre<br>grhgerhrehrehre<br>grhgerhrehrehre<br>grhgerhrehrehre<br>grhgerhrehrehre<br>grhgerhrehrehre<br>grhgerhrehrehre<br>grhgerhrehrehre<br>grhgerhrehrehre<br>grhgerhrehrehre<br>grhgerhrehrehre<br>grhgerhrehrehre<br>grhgerhrehrehre<br>grhgerhrehrehre<br>grhgerhrehrehre<br>grhgerhrehrehre<br>grhgerhrehrehre<br>grhgerhrehrehre<br>grhgerhrehrehre<br>grhgerhrehrehre<br>grhgerhrehrehre<br>grhgerhrehrehre<br>grhgerhrehrehre<br>grhgerhrehrehre<br>grhgerhrehrehre<br>grhgerhrehrehre<br>grhgerhrehrehre<br>grhgerhrehrehre<br>grhgerhrehrehre<br>grhgerhrehrehre<br>grhgerhrehrehre<br>grhgerhrehrehre<br>grhgerhrehrehre<br>grhgerhrehrehre<br>grhgerhrehrehre<br>grhgerhrehrehre<br>grhgerhrehrehre<br>grhgerhrehrehre<br>grhgerhrehrehre<br>grhgerhrehrehre<br>grhgerhrehrehre<br>grhgerhrehrehre<br>grhgerhrehrehre<br>grhgerhrehrehre<br>grhgerhrehrehre<br>grhgerhrehrehre<br>grhgerhrehrehre<br>grhgerhrehrehre<br>grhgerhrehrehre<br>grhgerhrehrehre<br>grhgerhrehrehre<br>grhgerhrehrehre<br>grhgerhrehrehre<br>grhgerhrehrehre<br>grhgerhrehrehre<br>grhgerhrehrehre<br>grhgerhrehrehre<br>grhgerhrehrehre<br>grhgerhrehrehre<br>grhgerhrehrehre<br>grhgerhrehrehre<br>grhgerhrehrehre<br>grhgerhrehrehre<br>grhgerhrehrehre<br>grhgerhrehrehre<br>grhgerhrehrehre<br>grhgerhrehrehre<br>grhgerhrehrehre<br>grhgerhrehrehre<br>grhgerhrehrehre<br>grhgerhrehrehre<br>grhgerhrehrehre<br>grhgerhrehrehre<br>grhgerhrehrehre<br>grhgerhrehrehre<br>grhgerhrehrehre<br>grhgerhrehrehre<br>grhgerhrehrehre<br>grhgerhrehrehre<br>grhgerhrehrehre<br>grhgerhrehrehre<br>grhgerhrehrehre<br>grhgerhrehrehre<br>grhgerhrehrehre<br>grhgerhrehrehre<br>grhgerhrehrehre<br>grhgerhrehrehre<br>grhgerhrehrehre<br>grhgerhrehrehre<br>grhgerhrehrehre<br>grhgerhrehrehre<br>grhgerhrehrehre<br>grhgerhrehrehre<br>grhgerhrehrehre<br>grhgerhrehrehre<br>grhgerhrehrehre<br>grhgerhrehrehre<br>grhgerhrehrehre<br>grhgerhrehrehre<br>grhgerhrehrehre<br>grhgerhrehrehre<br>grhgerhrehrehre<br>grhgerhrehrehre<br>grhgerhrehrehre<br>grhgerhrehrehre<br>grhgerhrehrehre<br>grhgerhrehrehre<br>grhgerhrehrehre<br>grhgerhrehrehre<br>grhgerhrehrehre<br>grhgerhrehrehre<br>grhgerhrehrehre<br>grhgerhrehrehre<br>grhgerhrehrehre<br>grhgerhrehrehre<br>grhgerhrehrehre<br>grhgerhrehrehre<br>grhgerhrehrehre<br>grhgerhrehrehre<br>grhgerhrehrehre<br>grhgerhrehrehre<br>grhgerhrehrehre<br>grhgerhrehrehre<br>grhgerhrehrehre<br>grhgerhrehrehre<br>grhgerhrehrehre<br>grhgerhrehrehre<br>grhgerhrehrehre<br>grhgerhrehrehre<br>grhgerhrehrehre<br>grhgerhrehrehre<br>grhgerhrehrehre<br>grhgerhrehrehre<br>grhgerhrehrehre<br>grhgerhrehrehre<br>grhgerhrehrehre<br>grhgerhrehrehre<br>grhgerhrehrehre<br>grhgerhrehrehre<br>grhgerhrehrehre<br>grhgerhrehrehre<br>grhgerhrehrehre<br></div>

</div>
  </body>
</html>
<script>
var uiBootstrapBlog = angular.module('uiBootstrapBlog', ['ngAnimate', 'ngSanitize', 'ui.bootstrap']);
 uiBootstrapBlog.controller('navbarCtrl', function($scope) {
 $scope.singleModel = false;
 var menuSlide = document.getElementById("main");
 $scope.singleModel === false ? menuSlide.style.left = "250px" : menuSlide.style.left = "0";
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not work because the codes gets called only once after the initialisation. Follow these three steps to fix the issue

1. Define a function and put `isCollapsedHorizontal` and the last two lines of code inside of it.
2. Your ternary operator has also an issue. Assign the variable that gets changed to the result of it.
3. Call the function inside the controller and with the `ng-click`.

```js
$scope.slideMenu = function() {
  $scope.isCollapsedHorizontal = !$scope.isCollapsedHorizontal;

  var menuSlide = document.getElementById("main");
  menuSlide.style.left = $scope.singleModel ? "250px" : "0";
}
$scope.slideMenu();
```

```html
<li style="font-size:30px; cursor:pointer;color:white" ng-click="slideMenu()" ng-model="singleModel" uib-btn-checkbox>&#9776;</li>
```